# Event tracking in UIScrollView blocks the main thread. Any fixes?

Tags: iphone

Event tracking in UIScrollview blocks the main thread.  I'm using the main thread to run a timer that drives some animation -- the result is that any user interaction with the scrollable view (dragging it up or down, etc) causes the animation (running on the main runloop) to freeze. Is there a way around this?

I've tried to RTFM about NSRunloop (CFRunLoopAddCommonMode et al), but it's pretty terse, leading me to believe that tinkering with event priorities / thread priorities is better avoided.   Anyone have any insight?

Comment: You can only do UI stuff in the main thread - so messing with thread priorities wouldn't apply. I am curious - do you know if the NSTimers stop firing, or do the timers fire, but refuse to apply the changes you make in the animation? Is the animation done *to* the UIScrollView, or *within* the scrollview? i.e. are you trying to animate and change the same thing that the scrollview scrolling is trying to change? (Scroll view rects, etc)?

Comment: Thanks, Brad -- what I was hoping (probably dangerously) to do was add the EventTracking mode to the main runloop, thereby allowing it to continue running concurrently with the EventTracking runloop.  The animation that's being blocked is actually being done on an entirely different view than the one containing the scrollview.   To answer your other question, the NSTimer stops firing altogether.  It seems completely blocked by the higher priority business of tracking the user events on the (unrelated) UIScrollView.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of using one of NSTimer's static constructors, create the timer object and schedule it manually for the "common" run loop modes:

Swift

```
let timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 10, repeats: false) { (_) in
    // ... do something useful after 10 seconds ...
}
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
```

Objective C

```
NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: delayInSeconds] interval: 0 target:yourObject selector:yourSelector userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop addTimer: timer forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Your paramters when constructing the timer will be different since you're using a repeating timer, but the basic idea is to manually schedule the timer for NSRunLoopCommonModes.

What's happening is that when you're scrolling the run loop goes into a mode which prevents "default mode" tasks from executing.  The static NSTimer functions all schedule into the default mode which is why they don't fire while you're scrolling.  Manually scheduling the timer lets you specify the mode and NSRunLoopCommonModes includes the run mode used by scrolling.

Comment: Brilliant!  I had been using:                                     [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:loopTimer forMode: [NSRunLoop currentMode]];   which was still blocked.   Your fix works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a trillion! This fix increases the usability of my lazy loading table drastically.

Comment: Perfect... working amazingly well. One note, for Swift 5.1, small change: `.commonModes` -> `RunLoop.Mode.common`

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to have the timer run on a separate thread. When the timer fires, then have what it needs to do run on the main thread.

**Edit:**

Ah yes, I totally forgot about how UIScrollView blocks pretty much everything. Another idea (albeit very ugly) is to check whether the timer fired during the delegate methods (i.e. `-scrollviewDidScroll`, etc.) of the UIScrollView. It's really sort of a hack, but it's basically the only way I'm aware of to get to execute any code during scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm actually already running my animation timer ON the main thread. It seems like the behind-the-scenes tracking of user events runs at a higher priority than the main thread, so when something continuous (like scrolling) happens, it blocks the main thread for a long time...